# How to do a nested list comprehension without making a product?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

In Python, I want to list all files in a set of directories. The best I'd like to get is a list. But at most I managed to make a nested list:

```
pics = os.path.expanduser('~/Pictures')
all_pics = [(d, os.listdir(d)) for d in os.listdir(pics)]
```

result:

```
[('folder1', ['file1', 'file2', ...]), ('folder2', ['file1', ...]), ...]
```

what I want:

```
[('folder1' 'file1'), ('folder1', 'file2'), ..., ('folder2', 'file1'), ...]
```

What I would like to get is a simple plain list, doesn't matter of what (can be of tuples), just so that it hasn't nested things, and I need no nested cycles in the code that parses it.

How can I do this with list comprehensions? Doing this gives me a product of 2 sets (dir names and filenames) which is wrong:

```
[(d, f) for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(pics, d)) for d in os.listdir(pics)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the order of the for-loops wrong.  It should be

```
all_pics = [(d, f)
            for d in os.listdir(pics)
            for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(pics, d))]
```

Outermost loop first, innermost loop last.

I wonder why you didn't get a `NameError` for `d`.

Comment: This fails if there's a file in the `pics` directory. See my answer.

Comment: @dancek: True, but somehow unrelated to the question.  Obviously, there are only directories in the directory the OP is interested in.  The question is why the OP's list comprehension does not work as expected.

Comment: Marmach: I actually agree that it's unrelated. It's just quite possible that at some point in the future, OP puts a file in `~/Pictures` and the script breaks. I see no harm in doing it the "right way" to begin with, but the other way around there's potential harm later on...

Answer (score 4):

Using `os.walk` is a better idea:

```
all_pics = [(dir,file)
            for dir,sub,files in os.walk(pics) 
            for file in files]
```

So why is it a better idea?

- it works with deeper trees, too (`subdir/subdir/pic.jpg`)
- it doesn't break if you put a file in `~/Pictures` (If you call `os.listdir` on files, you get `OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory`)
- it's simpler: `os.walk` does the traversing for you, all that remains is formatting the output

Comment: Apparently, there are only directories in the OP's `Pictures` directory.

Comment: I omitted a filter that I used (`os.path.isdir`)

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions work as a mapping from one list to another. As another poster pointed it you can do it by nesting them, but are you sure you really want to? You should favour readability over everything else, in all most all cases - and I don't consider the nested comprehension to be easily understandable.

```
What is wrong with? It might be marginally slower - but will you notice?

files = []
for d in os.listdir(pics):
    for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(pics, d)):
        files.append((d, f))
```

If you don't want to generate the list until absolutely necessary you could use a generator:

```
def get_file_mapping():
    for d in os.listdir(pics):
        for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(pics, d)):
            yield (d, f)
files = list(get_file_mapping())
```

Comment: I know about readability, but in this case I just wanted to know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [ [(d, f) for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(pics, d))] for d in os.listdir(pics) ]
l = sum(l, []) # flatten list of lists => list
```

Comment: This will create a list of lists of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to flatten your output list:

```
pics = os.path.expanduser('~/Pictures')
all_pics = reduce(lambda xs,ys: xs+ys, [(d, os.listdir(d)) for d in os.listdir(pics)])
```